# How to retrieve an error message in the php using json?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following php code:

```
if (($name == "") || ($email == "") || ($telephone == "") || ($username == "") ||       ($password == "")) {       

$ret = Array();
$ret["msg"] = "some input is missing";

echo json_encode($ret);
} elseif (!preg_match($pattern_email, $email)) {

$ret = Array();
$ret["msg"] = "email format is incorrect";

echo json_encode($ret);
} elseif (!preg_match($pattern_phone, $telephone)){

$ret = Array();
$ret["msg"] = "telephone should be all digits";

echo json_encode($ret);
}
```

and the following javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


$("#save").click(function(){

     var name = $('#name').val();
     var email = $('#email').val();
     var telephone = $('#telephone').val();
     var username = $('#username').val();
     var password = $('#password').val(); 

  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: 'contactData.php',

  dataType: "json",
   data:{"name":name,"telephone":telephone,"email":email, "username":username, "password":password},
   success: function(data) {
       //alert(data);
       var result = JSON.parse(data);
       $("#validate").html(data.msg);    


   }        
});

});
});
```

the aim of the program is to output an `error message` using json whenever one of the conditions is true. but I'm not retrieving any data and the program shows an error at the statement
 `var result = JSON.parse(data);`
Can anyone help plz???

Comment: did you echo your error msg?

Comment: im not receiving anything, blank

Comment: even alert(data) is not retrieving anything, it should retrieve the data from the php page right?? sry im new to php and ajax

Comment: you need to echo the response back to the client like `echo $errorMsg;` before `exit();`

Comment: You should't call `JSON.parse(data)` since `data` is already `JSON`

Comment: using the `dataType: json` should mean you don't have to parse using `JSON.parse` on the JS side... it should already be an object that is passed to your callback. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ read the `dataType` section.

Comment: if you are getting an empty `data` variable inside your callback, you should check that you are serving your JSON with the correct `content-type` i.e. with PHP you should use `header('content-type: application/json');` before you echo anything, otherwise certain user agents wont accept the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your PHP instead of

```
$errorMsg = '{"msg":"some input is missing"}';
```

Use

```
$ret = Array();
$ret["msg"] = "some input is missing";

echo json_encode($ret);
```

In your javascript

add in your ajax request

```
dataType: "json",
```

Your Parse will work now

Comment: can you edit your post with the code that you have tried plz?

Comment: You told me that you get blank in javascript. What if no one of your pregmatch is true in your PHP? try to echo some default value if no one preg_match match.

Comment: before itroducing json, when i echo without json im receiving data and an output message indicating the error is true so the problem is with json

Comment: So remove JSON.PARSE and alert the message and post it here

Comment: Just saying if you put datatype: json you have to remove the JSON.PARSE because the data is already in json

Answer (score 0):

You need create one array. After all validation in the end of code.

```
$data['respone'] = $errormsg;
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

In javascript you need to parse json object. And check if oject.element == '' then file else something wrong.